# Java: When are instance methods loaded in memory?

Tags: java, memory, static, instance

I would like to know that if I have the following class.

```
class Example {

public static void method1() {}

public void method2() {}

public void method3() {}
}
```

Only 1 method is static and it should be the first thing to be loaded in the memory during runtime. But what about the instance methods? Are they loaded in the memory when an instance of this class is created? Or are they already loaded when the class is loaded initially.

What I am trying to understand is if it is a better approach to have all the functionality in the same class by having separate methods for each functionality or is it better to create a separate class for each functionality with only there respective methods in its class.

So will it help memory wise in the later case because I will only create the instance of the class that I need to use and only that much of methods will be loaded in the memory. Otherwise, in the former case, where I have 100 methods in the same class, but I only need to use just 2 methods out of them, it will be waste of memory because all 100 methods are loaded.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually memory allocation for class variables and class member functions/methods are done differently. When a class is being instantiated its class variables are being created in the memory which is call as `data segment` and method codes are created in `code segment`. IF we create ten objects of a particular class java virtual machine will create ten different `code segments` but only one `code segment` will be created for all the object. Java virtual machine will create a `code segment` only when there is at least one reference to that that class object in the code else it will not.

Code segment captured minimal memory only. It just stores assembly instructions created from code. Hence you no need to worry about it. For object also a programmer no need to worry about managing the memory in Java as there is a garbage collector in java.

Now answer to your question in my comment section:-

> But will the methods themselves be stored somewhere in heap etc. ? So a class having 100 methods or 2 methods will behave the same memory wise?

As I said your method's codes will be converted into assembly instruction by your java virtual machine and will be  stored in the memory in an instruction pointer for each method. Not necessarily now many method, it will depends on lines of code, recursion, loops, and condition etc. Yes if 100 methods of same size of codes with all the above then it will takes more memory than two methods.

Comment: Hi Abhijit,

Thanks for your reply. 

I can understand what you are saying. I know that the variables inside the method will only consume memory when that method is called. But will the methods themselves be stored somewhere in heap etc. ? So a class having 100 methods or 2 methods will behave the same memory consumption wise?

Comment: @Manpreet, Please see my modified answer.